axisymmetric ODE $h=\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{rh'}{\sqrt{1+(h')^2}}\right).$
Consider the following equation where $h$ is a function of $y$:
\begin{equation*}
h=\frac{d}{dy}\left(\frac{h'}{\sqrt{1+(h')^2}}\right).
\end{equation*}
Multiplying both sides by $h'\equiv dh/dy$, and integrating the above equation, we get
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{2}h^2=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(h')^2}}+c,
\end{equation*}
where $c$ is a constant of integration.
Now consider the axisymmetric version of the same problem where $h$ is now a function of $r$, and $h'\equiv dh/dr$:
\begin{equation*}
h=\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{rh'}{\sqrt{1+(h')^2}}\right).
\end{equation*}
By multiplying it by a suitable function, can one integrate it once as in the previous case?

Hint: consider the change of variable $\rho = \ln r$.

How does integrating $h'(\frac{h'}{\sqrt{1+(h')^2}})'$ gives the RHS of the second equation?

@MOMO Differentiate the second equation and verify for yourself that you get the first.
